# Does it make sense to pre-train seq2seq models on length 1 input?

Tags: seq2seq

Does it make sense to pre-train seq2seq models on length 1 input? I have not found papers that would use this approach, but maybe someone has tried something like this.

Specifically, I want to have a seq2seq model with the input of multiple images, and the output of some vector. The data that I require is extremely limited, and difficult to obtain. I am planning to label some myself, and maybe even to pay on some website to obtain more labels. However, I am afraid that even this might not be enough.

However, there are many single-frame data available & synthetic single-frame data is easy to generate. So, would it make some sense to first train the seq2seq model on the single-frame data (i.e. sequences of length 1 & output of length 1), and then continue the training on the remaining multi-frame data for training the recurrent connections?

I will try it regardless, but if someone has some experience with it, or is aware of some related blog post / article / any other resource, I would be very grateful.

P.S. Are there better approaches than seq2seq for the image sequence -> numeric vectors modelling?

Comment: Could you give some more details about the task? I'm not quite sure what task you're trying to accomplish (i.e. why an image sequence? why is the output a numeric vector?) -- I'm also unclear on why this should be a seq2seq task.

Comment: @tchainzzz It is a pose estimation task, where the pose is just the vector of relative joint rotation of the pre-defined template. I've already seen the model working for the one-image case. However, I want to extend it to the videos, and also somehow incorporate the assumption that the pose in a frame is surely connected to the pose in the previous frame.